# LocalDateFormatter day of month cardinality

Tags: java, java-8, date-formatting, localdate

Is there a format pattern for LocalDateFormatter to display the cardinality of the day of the month, as well as other values?

For example, I wish to print 2016 November First, or 2017 February Twenty-seventh.

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

Comment: No, at the moment there is only numeric representation of the day-of-month field. Neither is there a way to plug-in your own fields into the default `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. You can' however, come up with your own parsing rules based on `date.getDayOfMonth()`. Exact rule will be dependent on whether or not you care about different locales and languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with the

```
public DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendText(TemporalField field, Map<Long, String> textLookup)
```

method that takes a `Map` which is used to look up the values for the field. Something like:

```
static final Map<Long, String> ORDINAL_DAYS = new HashMap<>();
static
{
  ORDINAL_DAYS.put(1, "First");
  ORDINAL_DAYS.put(2, "Second");
  ... values for month days 1 .. 31
  ORDINAL_DAYS.put(31, "Thirty-first");
}


DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendText(ChronoField.YEAR)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, ORDINAL_DAYS)
    .toFormatter();

String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

As M. Prokhorov already said, this is not built in. If you only need it for English locale, it shouldn’t be too hard, though:

```
private static final String[] dayNumberNames = { null, "first", "second",
        "third", // etc.
    };

public static String formatMyWay(LocalDate date) {
    String month = date.getMonth().toString();
    month = month.substring(0, 1) + month.substring(1).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return "" + date.getYear() + ' ' + month + ' ' + dayNumberNames[date.getDayOfMonth()];
}
```

This will give you something like

```
2017 February twenty-seventh
```

Polish to your taste.

The initial `null` element of the array is to compensate for the fact that array indices are 0-based while day numbers start at 1.

Comment: We can still use formatter to get the rest of the text, it's just the day-of-month we cannot obtain. So having `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMMM").format(date) + " " + dayNumberNames[date.getDayOfMonth()]` is fine. Obviously formatter should be saved somewhere to save on reparsing the same pattern.